# How can I solve this problem of NuGet packages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to compile my project with the library 'ImageProcessor' in its version = 2.7.0.100, but this error appears to me:

> Package 'ImageProcessor 2.7.0.100' was restored using '.NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework, version=v4.6.2, NETFramework, Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework, Version = v4.7.2, NETFramework=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp Version=v2.2' This package may not be fully compatible with your project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldytN.png)

How could I fix it? I need your help please coders.

Comment: find its source code, recompile using correct framework, pack, use your custom package source. but first make sure the license allows you to change the product

Comment: When you compile your project, does it throw any errors in red or just yellow warnings? When you run your code, whats red x errors you are getting?

Comment: Jawad hace WARMING >>> Project File Line Suppression State
Warning NU1701 Package 'ImageProcessor 2.7.0.100' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. ImageManager D:\publicados\FaceShooter API\FaceShooter API-1-TLS\FaceShooter API\ImageManager\ImageManager.csproj1

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a .NET Core 2.2 application.  The library you are trying to use, [ImageProcessor](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor), works with .NET Framework  only.  This is covered in [issue 639](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/issues/639) and [issue 776](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/issues/776) on the project site.

You will either need to create an application using .NET Framework, or try a different library.

Comment: thanks for your time. I will look for another library that is for .NETCore. Another library that can advise me?

Comment: The issues there recommend one.  I cannot, as I am not familiar (and would be off-topic here).

Comment: @MarceloEscalera, I've developed [ImageResize](http://demo.ziyad.info/tr/ImageResize) library, it depends on `System.Drawing.Common`, so for linux it requires installing gdi+ as described [here](https://github.com/LazZiya/ImageResize/issues/1)